# How to Post 'Comment' on my OWN wall - Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Very simple task in PHP/Facebook. I want to be able to Post a comment on my own page,

Currently I have downloaded and using the php_facebook graph api and am able to connect to FB and getmy User Data. But how do I post a comment ?

I would like something  like

```
$facebook->postOnWall('Hello World!');
```

Comment: thanks, yes im now heading in the right direction, I also noticed looking on developers.facebook that i will need not only the PHP SDK but the Javascript SDK. Ahhhg not as simple as I would have liked but its ok. thanks for the link.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330907/how-to-post-comment-on-my-own-wall-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: yup, this was def the simplest way to add to my site, but does not give me FULL programmatic control. Although right now its all i need. Thankyou